# Maven Company POM name

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to set up a (master/parent) company pom that will be used for projects. Now what is the most common name approuch for this?
Name the artifact after the company name or is using an artifact like "pom" also good?

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>company</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>pom</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

Because you have to make a seperated VCS for it also. And when you go for the first option (company/company) that repository can't be used for anything else. Or making a branch (named: pom) will solve this? Maybe it's just better to make a new repo for the pom?

https://github.com/company/company.git

https://github.com/company/pom.git

Comment: Do your company have a domain name (like foo.com or bar.co,uk).  Then use that reversed as your package base name (com.foo... or uk.co.bar...) and the base for your groupid.   You will need multiple groupids eventually.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points here:

- don't call it a 'master', master is a common shortening for 'aggegration-pom'. What you want is a parent.
- It is good practice to:

  - include the word `-parent` in your parent name
  - use the realm/scope of the parent in the name (`company` in your case)
  - also: the artifactId should be understandable by itself
  - give single version numbers (1 or 10 or 15 instead of 1.0) because you will seldom if ever use a bugfix version
  - use a single repository for your parent (yes, it is quite empty). But if it has a separate lifecycle, it should have a separate repository.

so, don't call it pom or company, because both is misleading:

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
```

If your company does other projects besides maven projects, it might also make sense to name the *repository* (not the artifactId) `company-maven-parent`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer and explanation! I will brainstorm about the right parent-pom name for my organization! Thanks.